# Find all Asian cities whose population is greater than population of every single Nordic country (attribute region)

Tags: sql

I'm doing a task where I'm supposed to find all Asian cities whose population is greater than the population of every single Nordic country (attribute region). (The diagram is shown on the uploaded picture below). I'm pretty new to SQL and I just wanted to ask, what is the right way to connect tables with foreign keys (in this case country code and code) so that I can approach both tables and put my conditions.

So far, my approach is:

```
SELECT city.Name
FROM wwd.city
JOIN wwd.country
ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
WHERE country.Continent='Asia' AND city.population > (SELECT city.population
                                                      FROM wwd.city
                                                      WHERE country.Region = 'Nordic'
```

I'm not sure If I used command JOIN properly as well as is the command JOIN expected in the second SELECT part?

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gESGr.jpg)

Comment: Looks like you forgot a closing parentheses. Is that a typo?

Comment: Work through [SQL Zoo](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/SELECT_from_WORLD_Tutorial) examples. It will give you a good start.

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question per post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to the given answer is to use the ALL operator:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp

```
SELECT
    city.Name
FROM
    wwd.city
    JOIN wwd.country ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
WHERE
    country.Continent = 'Asia'
    AND city.population > ALL (
        SELECT
            city.population
        FROM
            wwd.city
        WHERE
            country.Region = 'Nordic'
    )
```

As an aside, can you reference the country table in the subquery without joining it first with the city table?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following change:

```sql
SELECT
    city.Name
FROM
    wwd.city
    JOIN wwd.country ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
WHERE
    country.Continent = 'Asia'
    AND city.population > (
        SELECT
            max(city.population)
        FROM
            wwd.city
        WHERE
            country.Region = 'Nordic'
    )
```

Generally we want to compare in a 1:1 sort of way rather than directly comparing against a range.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm doing a task where I'm supposed to find all Asian cities whose population is greater than the population of every single Nordic country (attribute region).*

Your `WHERE` does not match your question, and you accepted an answer that used your `WHERE` logic. BUT, if you are actually looking for Asian cities with a population greater than every single Nordic country, you need something like the below:

```
SELECT
    city.Name
FROM
    wwd.city
    JOIN wwd.country ON city.CountryCode = country.Code
WHERE
    country.Continent = 'Asia'
    AND city.population > (
        SELECT
            SUM(country.population)
        FROM
            wwd.country
        WHERE
            country.Region = 'Nordic'
    )
```

Comment: I think the question is worded ambiguously and both interpretations are correct. In a real-world setting, there's usually enough context to determine how to proceed.